# Crashed when adding a really long line of code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using VS 2010 express for C#.

I am making a random chinese name generator.

I have nearly 200 thousands first name to be drawn.

When I add a really long code with these first names like

```
string[] firstname = new string[] {"A","B",...}
```

VS was in heavy load when I opened the project or attempted to click on the line. Actually, after adding the line, I cant even open the project.

I guess it is due to the auto-debugging function as it is not so laggy when I try to edit in notepad++.

Any recommendation on handling the problem of drawing a large set of elements?
Or how can I stop the auto-debugging function?

Comment: Load them from a file at runtime?

Comment: Yikes! Why don't you read them from a file?

Comment: I had thought of this but I somehow prefer "tidy" things. Is it possible to hide the file inside the exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] firstname = 
    System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("list-of-names-one-per-line.txt");
```

You should really consider reading from some kind of storage. This will also allow you to change the word list without recompiling your program.

If you  must, Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Advanced uncheck Show live semantic errors
[image: screencap]

Answer (score 2):

Read the values from a file. If you want to ensure the contents are included with an executable, then embed the file as a resource in the project and read the contents from there.